# Android Moto Droid 2.0.1 Home Screen

Tags: android, panel

Modify Current Home to 9 panels without changing anything else about the Desktop. Is this possible?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Please visit ForceClose.com for Android device questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's absolutely possible, but it would require you to build your own custom firmware to use it. The relevant code is in [the com.android.launcher package](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/launcher;h=ec8675413d9db1f821a810b2062030c9f40d16c0;hb=HEAD) and probably in the [Launcher class](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/com/android/launcher/Launcher.java;hb=HEAD).

This is a non-trivial problem.